# redirect to 404 page automatically at laravel 5.4

Tags: php, database, laravel, controller, routes

i made simple resume site with laravel 5.4 and i wanna if users type anything except my site name and my site.com/panel automatically redirect to 404 page.

how can i do that?

is there any route to do that or what?

i found this code but not use

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof 
    \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException){

        return response(redirect(url('/')), 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);

}
```

Comment: As per docs **"create a  `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`. This file will be served on all 404 errors generated by your application."**

Comment: thanks man.it worked :)

Comment: @linktoahref is right, I am just adding the correct link to Laravel 5.5 documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors and full quote where it says: `Laravel makes it easy to display custom error pages for various HTTP status codes. For example, if you wish to customize the error page for 404 HTTP status codes, create a  resources/views/errors/404.blade.php. This file will be served on all 404 errors generated by your application. The views within this directory should be named to match the HTTP status code they correspond to.`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

just add `abort` method

```
 return abort(404);
```

it's automatically redirect to your `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`

Comment: This doesn't change the URL to /404 though.

Comment: @braed Never mind, because you are showing the 404 page indicating that such URL does not exists.

Comment: the function **abort** is void, so you don't need return

Answer (score 5):

```
return abort(404);
```

and set your routes too for this particular action/method with get request.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, you may provide the response text:

```
return abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a view in

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

and it will redirect every unexist route that you didn't include it in

```
 web.php
```

and in 404.blade file you can put this hyper link to redirect use to your home page
either by choosing route name

```
<a href="{{ route('home') }}">Back to home</a>
```

or by specifying a route link directly

```
<a href="/">Back to home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

create this page first

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

after that put this code on "404.blade.php" file

```
{{redirect()->to('/')->send()}}
```